# Using IN condition in CQL for partition keys without performace degradation

Tags: java, cassandra, cql, anti-patterns, where-in

I already know about anti-pattern with using IN (https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlSelect.html#cqlSelect__selectInNot).

But what if I have set of partition keys which belong to same TokenRnage?

So, suppose we have next code:

```
public ResultSet getDataForFirstTokenRange(List<String> initialKeys)
    Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(DEFAULT_SEEDS)
      .withClusterName(DEFAULT_CLUSTER_NAME).build();
    Metadata meta = cluster.getMetadata();
    Set<TokenRange> tokens = meta.getTokenRanges();
    TokenRange firstTr = tokens.iterator().next();

    List<String> filteredKeys = filterKeysForToken(firstTr, initialKeys, meta)
    return session.execute(
         "select * from MY_TABLE where key IN (" + 
              String.join(
                   ", ", 
                   filteredKeys.stream()
                       .map(key -> "'" + key + "'")
                       .collect(Collectors.toList())
              )  + 
              ")"
    );
}

private List<String> filterKeysForToken(TokenRange tr, List<String> keys, Metadata meta) {
    return keys.stream()
            .filter(key -> {
                Token token = meta.newToken(TypeCodec.varchar().serialize(
                        key, 
                        ProtocolVersion.NEWEST_SUPPORTED
                ));
                return tr.contains(token);
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

So, here I filter initial list of partition key, so that result list belong only to one TokenRange.

And after it I make query.

So the question is, will there be performance problems here?
And if not, will this approach be better than execution separate query for each partition key?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you already know that the partition key tells Cassandra in which node data is stored.

Functionally, having multiple async queries and an IN clause is the same stuff: you'll hit one single node in the cluster. However, having an IN clause should be a major performance hit because the coordinator waits for all data to be available before returning the answer to the client. On the contrary, if you issue multiple async queries you have separate flows to the client, one for each query, and you should be able to *process* your data faster.